# How to access the current Rack::Session implementation

Tags: ruby, rack

I am working on a gem that will need to read and write to not just to the current session, but to other "linked" sessions. Right now I am hard-coding reads and writes to the underlying session store we are using in our rails and rack apps whenever I need to update a session other than the current one. But, a more generic approach would be needed to make the solution portable to other session implementations.

In Rails apps I can look at `Rails.application.config.session_store` to determine the session storage implementation, and instantiate a new instance to read and write to sessions beyond the current session. Generating another instance of the session store seems a bit inefficient, but it does seem to work.

However, I can't figure out any way to query the current session store through a Rack app. `env['rack.session']` and `env['rack.session.options']` don't provide any insight.

The best solution would be to access the already-instantiated Rack::Session Rack app in the middleware stack. I'm not sure how to query what middleware is running and which one is the current Rack::Session implementation (just check which one is a decendent of `Rack::Session::Abstract::ID`?).

Any tips for querying the middleware or alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the session in rack using `request.cookies["rack.session"]`.  Rack < 1.0 used to allow you to actually pass session variables in through a request, [but it has been disabled in newer versions of rack for security purposes](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/332-Testing-sessions-with-Sinatra-and-Rack-Test).  I know it's kind of late but hopefully this helps you.